# Cannot add submenu to menu in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I got this code (simple wordpress plugin).

```
add_menu_page('Basket Stats', 'Basket Stats', 'manage_options', 'basket_stats', 'basket_stats_plugin_page', '', 71);
add_submenu_page('admin.php?page=basket_stats', 'Basket Stats', 'Basket Stats', 'manage_options', 'basket_stats', 'basket_stats_plugin_page');
```

First line makes new menu and the second is supposed to make second menu. When I change *admin.php?page=basket_stats* to something default like *tools.php* it all works fine. I tried changing it to *basket.php* (the file that this code is into) but with no effects.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fourth parameter should be **FILE**, like:

```
add_menu_page('Basket Stats', 'Basket Stats', 'manage_options', __FILE__, 'basket_stats_plugin_page', '', 71);
```

everything works after that. It is also possible to change slugs in submenu to **FILE** too.